# Extract matching pattern in logstash-grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I've got a fairly lengthy match statement, like

```
    grok {
        patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/pattern"]
        match => ["message", "%{PATTERN_1}",
                  "message", "%{PATTERN_2}",
                 # ... many more following
                  "message", "%{PATTERN_N}"]
        tag_on_failure => []
        add_tag => [ "parsed" ]
    }
```

Is there a way to extract the name of the matching pattern into a new field, e.g. "match_pattern": "PATTERN_1"?

I've tried with named pattern:
match => ["message", "%{PATTERN_1:PATTERN_1}"]
which copies the message field to a new field named PATTERN_1. What I need is a given field the matching pattern name is assigned to.
Any ideas?